# react-router v6 and nested deployment

Tags: react-router

I'm using v6 and vite.js and deploying the built app into a nested directory. Despite specifying the basename attribute in the BrowserRouter element, I'm finding the URLs don't work correctly unless coming in via the index.html. I can work around this with a .htaccess file but it seems like a bit of a hack. Can someone suggest a better alternative?  Thanks!

Comment: It all mostly depends on the server environment where the app is deployed. For example, it's common to edit the `.htaccess` file on Apache servers. Take a look at the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) for configuring various server environments to see if there's something relevant to yours.